# Make .htaccess redirect spamy links that start with ? to an error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have tried lots of code and now I'm here.  Is there a way I can redirect spamy links back to a 404 error or 410 error gone page, through my .htaccess file (it's a wordpress site)  the links all start with a ? mark - so for example they are:  www.mydomain.com/?spam-link-here link, right now they are all going to the home page and I would like them to go to either a 404 or 410 error page.  So it needs to be something that targets a query string that starts with a ? mark targeted code.

**FYI I have hardened my htaccess file, just need help with this part, thanks

in the root directory .htaccess I put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Get the strings but no empty strings because of home failure
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .

# AND try to exclude normal searches, CSS and Javascript:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^c=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ver=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login\.php

# AND try not to rewrite specific directories:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-content/

# Do it
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com.au/$1? [G,NC]
```

And in the wp-admin I put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(edit\.php|edit-tags\.php|upload\.php|link-manager\.php|post-new\.php|post\.php|admin\.php|themes\.php|widgets\.php|theme-editor\.php|plugin-install\.php|plugin-editor\.php|profile\.php|tools\.php|customize\.php|nav-menus\.php|users\.php|options-general\.php|options-writing\.php|options-media\.php|options-reading\.php|options-discussion\.php|options-media\php|options-permalink\.php|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com.au/$1? [G,NC]
```

Messed up the dashboard; which I wouldn't even care about it if it made the spamy links re-direct to an error page.  I tried tons of other code in there; this code worked for another guy but it's not working for me...not sure why.

Here's the link from the other thread, I was so hoping it finally get solved here on stackoverflow.  [thread where I got the latest set of code](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wild-card-redirect-using-htaccess?replies=33)

Answer (score 1):

I got some other extra help and this is what finally seems to be working, return a 404 response on any URL that includes a query string with no = symbol.

```
###BAD QUERY STRING BLOCKER, ADDED 5/26/2016
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[\-/A-Z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404]
</IfModule>
###END CODE
```

Seems to be at least re-directing the spamy links to an error page!

Answer (score 0):

The [`G`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_g) flag already returns a 410 status code, so it shouldn't redirect to the home page.

Maybe there's an [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) somewhere or some other rule redirecting error status codes to your home page. When this is the case, you must replace this directive with a real error page, e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-410.html
```

You must also guard against an endless loop somewhere at the top of your rules with

```
RewriteRule ^error-410\.html$ - [L]
```

Then your "gone" rule can be simplified to just

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=(.*)$
...
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```