# .htaccess - Combatting String Query Spam, Custom 404 redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, malware

Been trying to clean up the aftermath of a decode64 content injection hack on multiple sites on my shared server.

It's clean, but now I'm getting links of incoming spam links with query string, like abc.com/?some-stupid-porno-spam/, so even though the content no longer exists, they're still being redirected to the front page. Am ranking for these spam words instead, or google's just saying those are soft-404s for the luckier sites.

Got a solution, but it's temporary. I was advised to add the following to the top of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [L,R=404]
```

So, now all links with /? are redirected to a 404. 2 problems:

1. It's temporary, in that ALL /? queries are thrown to the 404, including wordpress post/page previews. Is there are way to make it such that it only works for non-existent pages?
2. The 404 points to the webhosts 404. How can I make it such that it goes to the theme's 404 instead?

Thanks for your time!

------ update

So, the above code works great. I can preview posts/pages, but I found there's a problem - it blocks wordpress' WYSIWYG text editor. The 'visual' tab remains blank, and none of the toolbars appear.

Help? lol

Comment: could you add a dump of those request in your apache log files here?

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/37442605/1741542, see `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !...`

Comment: looks like the code on that post works! thanks! 

post/page previews on wordpress have '=' in the string and the code he uses allows those strings to be viewed.

now I just have to figure out the themed 404 thing

Comment: So, the above code works great. I can preview posts/pages, but I found there's a problem - it blocks wordpress' WYSIWYG text editor. The 'visual' tab remains blank, and none of the toolbars appear.

Help? lol